# Hadoop 3 DataNode process not running (Permissions Issue)

Tags: hadoop, ubuntu-18.04

Trying to get Hadoop 3.2.2 up and running on Ubuntu 18.

Followed this tutorial. https://phoenixnap.com/kb/install-hadoop-ubuntu

Tried to troubleshoot, I read this thread: [Datanode process not running in Hadoop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11889261/datanode-process-not-running-in-hadoop?rq=1)

Examined Datanode log, saw permissions issue.

Because Part 5 of the 12-vote answer in the above-linked thread seemed the most relevant, I did this:

```
cd dfsdata
sudo chmod -R 755 datanode
cd ..
cd hadoop-3.2.2
cd sbin
./stop-all.sh
hadoop namenode -format
start-all.sh
jps
```

But still no DataNode in the list.

(This was slightly out of order from the suggested process; I did not stop-all before changing permissions, does that matter?)

Datanode log file:

```
************************************************************/
2021-06-02 15:14:24,546 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: registered UNIX signal handlers for [TERM, HUP, INT]
2021-06-02 15:14:25,607 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.checker.ThrottledAsyncChecker: Scheduling a check for [DISK]file:/home/hdoop/dfsdata/datanode
2021-06-02 15:14:25,737 WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.checker.StorageLocationChecker: Exception checking StorageLocation [DISK]file:/home/hdoop/dfsdata/datanode
EPERM: Operation not permitted
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.chmodImpl(Native Method)
        at org.apache.hadoop.io.nativeio.NativeIO$POSIX.chmod(NativeIO.java:382)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.RawLocalFileSystem.setPermission(RawLocalFileSystem.java:863)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$1.apply(ChecksumFileSystem.java:510)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem$FsOperation.run(ChecksumFileSystem.java:491)
        at org.apache.hadoop.fs.ChecksumFileSystem.setPermission(ChecksumFileSystem.java:513)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.mkdirsWithExistsAndPermissionCheck(DiskChecker.java:234)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDirInternal(DiskChecker.java:141)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker.checkDir(DiskChecker.java:116)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.StorageLocation.check(StorageLocation.java:239)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.StorageLocation.check(StorageLocation.java:52)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.checker.ThrottledAsyncChecker$1.call(ThrottledAsyncChecker.java:142)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask$TrustedFutureInterruptibleTask.runInterruptibly(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:125)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.InterruptibleTask.run(InterruptibleTask.java:57)
        at com.google.common.util.concurrent.TrustedListenableFutureTask.run(TrustedListenableFutureTask.java:78)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
2021-06-02 15:14:25,740 ERROR org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Exception in secureMain
org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Too many failed volumes - current valid volumes: 0, volumes configured: 1, volumes failed: 1, volume failures tolerated: 0
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.checker.StorageLocationChecker.check(StorageLocationChecker.java:231)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.makeInstance(DataNode.java:2806)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.instantiateDataNode(DataNode.java:2721)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.createDataNode(DataNode.java:2763)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.secureMain(DataNode.java:2907)
        at org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode.main(DataNode.java:2931)
2021-06-02 15:14:25,742 INFO org.apache.hadoop.util.ExitUtil: Exiting with status 1: org.apache.hadoop.util.DiskChecker$DiskErrorException: Too many failed volumes - current valid volumes: 0, volumes configured: 1, volumes failed: 1, volume failures tolerated: 0
2021-06-02 15:14:25,760 INFO org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: SHUTDOWN_MSG:
/************************************************************
SHUTDOWN_MSG: Shutting down DataNode at ip-172-31-94-192.ec2.internal/172.31.94.192
************************************************************/
```

Previous threads are a little confusing to me because they indicate different folder names and things like that, probably due to using previous versions of hadoop and/or different setup processes.

EDIT:
Also tried doing stop-all, changing permissions on both datanode and namenode, and start-all. Didn't seem to change anything.

EDIT 2: This thread actually looks very similar: [Hadoop datanode not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33822453/hadoop-datanode-not-running?rq=1)

Answer (score 0):

This thread provided the answer: [Hadoop datanode not running](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33822453/hadoop-datanode-not-running?rq=1)

I had created the dfsdata folder as root account rather than as hdoop account, so just had to chown -R that and "power cycle" the hadoop processes.